# Centre aligning a div using viewport coordinates

Tags: html, css

I am learning `CSS`, I am new to this field. Please excuse me if my questions is naive.

I have a simple `HTML` containing 1 `div`.

```css
.square {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  margin-left: 5vw;
  margin-right: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<head>
  <link href="viewport-cord.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class='square'></div>
</body>
```

I am expecting a margin of 5% of viewport width on both sides of the `div`. However, it seems that we have broader gap in the left side of div compared to right. I am not sure where these extra margin is coming from.

[image: Image showing the div when opened in chrome with dev tools showing margins.]

Comment: Note: the `<link>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:
Give max with and then subtract 10% (5% each side), then center square with margin auto.

**CSS**

```
.square {
    background-color: blue;
    width: calc(100vw - 10%);
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/x09ygk6p/3/)**

Comment: I want to understand why there is more gap on left side compared to right.

Comment: Because you have default margin in the body, html. Just do this `body,html{margin:0;}`

Comment: Yes, I think we are getting a margin of 8px from User Agent style sheet. 8px margin is on both sides. However, still (if I don't reset the margin of body and html to 0) left gap is around 69 pixel and right gap is 53 pixel. I measured it using taking a screenshot and using preview app on mac.

Comment: Certainly, if you are using only viewport measure you will get sizes from view port. From left to right you will get 5vw + (Browser default margin) and then it will ignore the right margin because is not right in mathematic (margin 10vw + 90vw + browser margins). If you set your margin, use like my answer in percentage. this will make a better adjustments and good mathematic (viewport and in the fact the margins of the elements).

Comment: That was what I also suspected but I was not sure that browser will drop its user agent styles in these cases.

Comment: I have edited your answer a bit, could you please rephrase it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you are new to HTML & CSS, let me give you a breif description on how to adjest widht of an element based on the viewport.

---

### Viewport

The viewport is the area of your browser where **the actual content is displayed** - in other words your web browser without its toolbars and buttons. The units are `vw`, `vh`, `vmin` and `vmax`. They all represent a percentage of the browser (viewport) dimensions and scale accordingly on window resize.

Lets say we have a viewport of 1000px (width) by 800px (height):

- vw - Represents 1% of the viewport's width. In our case 50vw = 500px.
- vh - A percentage of the window's height. 50vh = 400px.
- vmin - A percentage of the minimum of the two.

In our example 50vmin = 400px
   since we are in landscape mode. vmax - A percentage of the bigger
   dimension. 50vmax = 500px.

You can use these units anywhere that you can specify a value in pixels, like in `width`, `height`, `margin`, `font-size` and **more**. They will be recalculated by the browser on window resize or device rotation.

---

### case 1

Now considering your issue, I don't see any change in width on either side, because if you see your *inspector->layout->margin* I can see both sides showing **64** on the screenshot you provided.

### case 2

If you really do see the change in your system again. Try removing the external CSS you have mentioned to see if that's causing any issue and then put `margin:0px` for html and body.

Hope this help's you out...